# Website IP Address through terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

In windows we can find IP address of any website though following command:

`tracert www.example.com`

What is the replacement of this command in linux??

I am using 'elementary os loki'.

Comment: Your question is off topic for Stack Overflow, which is for programming questions only.

Comment: Install `traceroute` package; it's the equivalent of `tracert` of windows!

Comment: take a look at the `nslookup` and `dig` commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nslookup example.com |grep Address

Answer (score 1):

You May Install `sudo apt-get install traceroute`

and

```
traceroute www.google.com > myfile.txt
```

You May Refer From [Askubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=916640)